# Are there any national brands of tuna that are Bishul Yisroel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, fish, bishul-akum

Are there any national brands of tuna in the USA that are Bishul Yisroel?

Comment: Can you provide motivation and background for the issues this question is trying to address?

Comment: @bondonk: Motivation is getting tuna with Bishul Yisrael at a reasonable price.

Comment: Isn't all tuna with a Hekhsher Bishul Yisrael? Why would anyone put a Hekhsher on something not Kosher?

Comment: @DoubleAA: To the best of my knowledge OU certified tuna is not Bishul Yisrael. See [here](http://cor.ca/view/196/can_a_can_of_tuna_have_kosher_considerations.html) this article from COR Canada

Comment: @GershonGold The OU is certifying Bishul Akum??? Chas veShalom. Maybe "Bishul Yisrael" is an unclear term here and you should better clarify in your post what kind of tuna you are looking for. You want a Jew to do what with the tuna at what stage in the process?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Yes. They hold there is no need for Bishul Yisrael on tuna.

Comment: Maybe they (or someone) just hold steaming isn't Bishul? Everyone would certainly agree you can't have Bishul Akum on tuna. (Why not just say what you seek instead of using ambiguous terminology?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the Star-K ones are and OU tuna that is Kosher LPesach is also.

Comment: I think for Pesach BumbleBee does a premium production in goldish-colored cans that is OU Kosher for Passover, and Bishul Yisrael as well.  They're available a few weeks before Passover.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for Bishul Yisrael according to the opinion of the Rema(and thus Ashkenazim), yes there are.  According to the Mechaber(and thus Sephardim), no there are not.  There are a couple of brands that are imported from Israel that meet Sephardi criteria.

Comment: Do you know Hacham Ovadia's Teshuva about eating at restaurants? If so, do you think it applies to tuna?

Comment: Please provide sources (or sauces!)

Comment: The star-k now makes star-s that is kosher for sefardim

Answer (score 2):

"California" brand tuna is bishul yisrael

Answer (score 1):

Dagim is always and only Bishul Yisroel

Comment: That's not true at all in any way whatsoever in the slightest

Comment: Sorry to refer to this old thread. Your comment intrigued me during a recent interest in this topic for a similar type of food product. Are you suggesting that Dagim with CRC certification is not BY? Source?

Answer (score 0):

Some brands of organic/sustainable Tuna that can be found in the health food section of a grocery store will have "BY" stamped on the top of the can. This means it is from a special Bishul Yisroel run at the factory.